# %PUT - print dates and times in format from numeric macro variable

Tags: date, sas, format

I've got this problem which seems so easy.

I've got macro like:

```
%macro test;

    /* I start from it */
    %let time_ = %sysfunc(time());
    %let date_ = %sysfunc(date());

    %let time1 = %sysfunc(time());
        data _null_;
            timedelay = sleep(5, 1);
        run;
    %let time2 = %sysfunc(time());

    %let diff = %sysevalf(&time2 - &time1);

    %put Timenow: &time_;
    %put DateNOw: &date_;
    %put TimeDifference: &diff;
    /*Above works as I want*/

    /* What I want to have */
    %put Timenow: %sysfunc(put(&time_, time13.)); /* Timenow: 22:06:00 */
    %put DateNOw: %sysfunc(put(&time_, date9.)); /* DateNOw: 27FEB2019 */
    %put TimeDifference: %sysfunc(put(&time_, time13.)); /* TimeDifference: 00:00:05 */


%mend;

%test;
```

So basically e.g. instead  `%sysfunc(put(&time_, time13.));` something similar that would give me result: `22:06:00`
Is there a easy and straight forward method to do it?

Thanks!

Comment: You must use PUTC/PUTN functions with SYSFUNC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SYSFUNC has a format option.  Consider if this is useful for you.

```
%let time1 = %sysfunc(datetime());
   data _null_;
      timedelay = sleep(5, 1);
      run;
%let time2 = %sysfunc(datetime());

%let diff = %sysfunc(sum(&time2,-&time1),time13.);
%put NOTE: &=diff;
```

[image]

Or if you want to use PUTN function.

```
%put TimeDifference: %sysfunc(putN(%sysevalf(&time2-&time1),time,13));
```

[image]

Comment: It's important for me to derive it from just difference - it's also used in different place. I new about that option in %sysfunc. Sorry I didn't clarify it more.

Comment: @MateuszKonopelski sounds like you just need to replace PUT with PUTN function.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Please change your original post and I will mark it as answer. Thanks!

Comment: Note that there is no need to use the `%sysevalf()` inside the argument to `putn()`.  The `%sysfunc()` call will push the equation into normal SAS processing to be evaluated as part of evaluating the `putn()` function call.